# "Съешь еще этих мягких французских булок"

Tags: литература

Эта фраза используется для демонстрации начертания компьютерных шрифтов. А откуда она вообще взята?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, в этой фразе присутствуют все (или почти все) буквы русского алфавита (проверьте сами).

Comment: Ну, сразу вижу: нет букв Ы, Э, Ю, Я, Д — остальные лень проверять))

Comment: Да, еще нет В и Д. Но зато есть "редкие"буквы - Ъ, например и шипящие.

Comment: Граждане, ну фразу-то надо целиком рассматривать.

*"Съешь же ещё этих мягких французских булок да выпей чаю".*
А Э есть даже в укороченном варианте.

Вот вам ещё вариант "на проверку". )))
*"В чащах юга жил-был цитрус, да, но фальшивый экземпляр."*
Остальные уже подзабыл.

Comment: Вот спасибо! А то я еще удивлялась, почему так много пропущенных букв!

Comment: Тогда вам будет интересно.
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0

Comment: Спасибо, интересно. По-английски фразы выглядят естественней, видимо, из-за отсутствия таких редких букв, как шипящие, ъ. Для них приходится подбирать весьма странные слова. Я как-то пробовала - занятие не из легких.

Answer (score 5):

Фраза не "взята". Она придумана специально для проверки работоспособности печатающих устройств. О "шрифтах" тогда и речи не было. Подобных фраз было довольно много, но для современной техники это не слишком актуально.

Comment: Смешно то, что вы хвастаетесь, но не предъявляете.  
Особенно интересуют допущения.

Comment: behemothus, я в Вашем комментарии увидел слово "хвастаетесь" и вспомнил, как много лет назад мой преподаватель в университете исправил меня, когда я произнес это слово, и сказал, что оно употребляется без возвратной частицы "ся". Может быть, что-то изменилось с тех пор?

Comment: Интересный вопрос...
Чтобы судить об том, изменилось ли что-то, надо точно знать, как оно было до того. Я - не берусь. Кузнецов считает варианты синонимичными.  
Я отчасти готов согласиться с преподавателем, что хвастаться - это в первую очередь общая характеристика субъекта или производителя действия (как "собака кусается"), а чем-то конкретным скорее хвастают, а не хвастаются.

Но в любом случае я не следил за правильностью речи, а скорее имитировал нечто из детского сада: "Марьванна, а Вовка дерется, плюется, писается, дразнится, хвастается..."

Comment: Детский сад прописан еще у Фасмера, глянул бы преподаватель, который "оборвал" студента... в те времена словарь был издан. Не ВСЕМ ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛЯМ МОЖНО В РОТ СМОТРЕТЬ, надо и самим тему досконально исследовать, если не совсем ...любой "препод" тоже человек, ему свойственно все, что свойственно обычному студенту, ну, просто не в курсе. Но курс преподает, пре -- частица интересная, в сочетании подавать... сначала надо пре, или при... готовиться.

Comment: Вы, fatyalink, уже прото заговариваетесь. При чем здесь вообще Фасмер и преподавательский рот? Я "детским садом" назвал свой стиль. Грумант потер комментарий, на который и был мной дан ответ с  "хвастаетесь".

Answer (score 2):

Полностью эта фраза звучит как `"Съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок, да выпей же чаю"` и применяется потому, что в ней присутствуют все буквы русского алфавита. Такие фразы называются "панграммы", и в современности применяются в основном для демонстрации шрифтов.

Приведённая фраза применяется в windows, да ещё и без частицы "же". Насколько я понимаю, автором фразы является кто-то из Microsoft.

А вот, например, в KDE применяется `"Широкая электрификация южных губерний даст мощный толчок подъёму сельского хозяйства"`.

Подобных фраз довольно много. Моя любимая такова: `"Эй, жлоб! Где туз? Прячь юных съёмщиц в шкаф"`.

Comment: Я эту фразу слышал когда не то что Виндуза, Микрософта еще не было. Середина семидесятых.

Comment: >А вот, например, в KDE применяется "Широкая электрификация южных губерний даст мощный толчок подъёму сельского хозяйства".

Моё почтение пользователям свободного программного обеспечения :-)

В Линукс Минт (Мате и Синнамон) и в Убунту (Юнити), которые на основе *Гнома*, там используется фраза:

> В чащах юга жил бы цитрус? Да, но фальшивый экземпляр!

Comment: @behemothus, охотно верю. С удовольствием ознакомился бы со ссылкой на какие-нибудь печатные источники, содержавшие это в семидесятые.

@Nikolja справедливости ради, во фразе из гнома нету "ё", "й", "ъ"

Comment: >во фразе из гнома нету "ё", "й", "ъ"

**"Фальшивый"**? 

Букв "ё" и "ъ" действительно нет.

К слову, на этот сайт я сейчас зашёл из под *Linux Mint KDE*. :-)

Comment: >С удовольствием ознакомился бы со ссылкой на какие-нибудь печатные источники, содержавшие это в семидесятые.  
  
Вы серьезно думаете, что их не сдали в макулатуру уже в восьмидесятые? Тогда ищите документацию по печатным устройствам серии ЕС и игольчатым принтерам "Роботрон". С последним, правда, я столкнулся уже в 81 г. Но моднючая штука была... Немецкая. Вот не помню, какой конкретно фразой его проверяли... Кажется как раз цитрусом. А булками - это барабанные станки. И, вроде, консоль ЕС.